# Deleting large Django QuerySets is causing an Apache Internal Server Error

Tags: django, django-queryset, bulk

I am trying to do delete roughly 200,000 objects (which all have multiple related objects, totalling roughly 2,000,000 objects) using:

```
DataRecord.objects.filter(order=self.order).delete()
```

But I am getting an Internal Server Error (after about 20 minutes or so), and none of the objects are deleted. I have the Apache timeout set to 3600 (1 hour) to give enough time for this operation.

Is there a more efficient way to delete a very large number of objects in bulk?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the best solution is to use a raw query (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly ), but `pre_delete`, `post_delete` signals will not be fired.

random ORM idea: is `DataRecord.order` column indexed?

edit:
to recognize if column is easy: see if column has set `db_index` property, ie:

```
class DataRecord(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(_("order"), **db_index=True**)
```

Index allows to find data fast, without reading the whole table. It's like an index in a book - when you want to find some word in there, index will help you to find it out without reading the whole book.

Comment: I friend of mine mentioned the raw SQL option as well.  I will have to try it and compare the speed/performance to the individual deletion I currently have working.  He also asked about indexing.  I only know the basics of SQL, how would indexing help or hurt in this situation?  How do I know if they are indexed?

Comment: @Brian added note about indexing

Answer (score 2):

Find the number of the objects that are going to be deleted and break down the deletion to multiples of one thousand or so in a for loop.
A simple example:

```
q = DataRecord.objects.filter(order=self.order)
cnt = q.count()
bucket = 1000
a, rem = divmod(cnt, bucket) 
i, j, k = 0, bucket, 0
while k<a:
    for obj in q[k*bucket: (k+1)*bucket + (k+1==a and rem)]:
        obj.delete()
    k+=1
```

Comment: I tried this:  DataRecord.objects.filter(order=order)[:1000].delete(), but it raised an AssertionError: Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with delete. Are you saying to delete each object individually?

Comment: exactly. You cannot use limit or offset. So you have to delete each object "manually". Give my code a try.

Comment: How is this method different than just iterating through the entire queryset and deleting each object individually?  I was told making calls to the DB within a loop like this was a bad practice.  Although, I will admit, it works.

Comment: There is an error with the way you assign the value of variable a. If there are less than bucket number of items in the result of the query, then while loop does not work and items are not deleted. You need to check if a == 0 and make it a = 1 if so.